# converting a PHP for loop to a for each

Tags: php, algorithm, for-loop, foreach

Im not soo comfortable in algorithms can somebody please help me to convert this for loop to a foreach please

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($cartBookItems); $i++) {
    $currentCartBookItem = $cartBookItems[$i];
    if($currentCartBookItem->getBookID() == $book->getId()) {
        $newQuantity = $currentCartBookItem->getQuantity() + $quantity;
        $currentCartBookItem->setQuantity($newQuantity);
        $isItemAlreadyExists = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first question that comes up here is: Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($cartBookItems as $each_book_item) {
    $currentCartBookItem = $each_book_item;
       if($currentCartBookItem->getBookID() == $book->getId()) {
             $newQuantity = $currentCartBookItem->getQuantity() + $quantity;
             $currentCartBookItem->setQuantity($newQuantity);
             $isItemAlreadyExists = true;             
       }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @castis for the suggestion. You can directly have `$currentCartBookItem` as you loop iteratable variable.

```
foreach($cartBookItems as $currentCartBookItem ) {
       if($currentCartBookItem->getBookID() == $book->getId()) {
             $newQuantity = $currentCartBookItem->getQuantity() + $quantity;
             $currentCartBookItem->setQuantity($newQuantity);
             $isItemAlreadyExists = true;             
       }
}
```

Comment: make it `$cartBookItems as $currentCartBookItem` to further simplify.

Comment: @castis Thanks updated :)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($cartBookItems as $bookItem) {
    $currentCartBookItem = $bookItem;
    if($currentCartBookItem->getBookID() == $book->getId()) {
        $newQuantity = $currentCartBookItem->getQuantity() + $quantity;
        $currentCartBookItem->setQuantity($newQuantity);
        $isItemAlreadyExists = true;
    }
}

//or

foreach($cartBookItems as $bookItem) {
    if($bookItem->getBookID() == $book->getId()) {
        $newQuantity = $bookItem->getQuantity() + $quantity;
        $bookItem->setQuantity($newQuantity);
        $isItemAlreadyExists = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$cartBookItems as $currentCartBookItem` would require less code changes.